# How to get address on map clicking on link address?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eB2RX/182/ What i want is when user click on address on right side that map find that address. Any suggestion how can i do this?

```
 $(".location_address a").click(function(e){
     getLatLong("Travnik");
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the name of the city you clicked to `getLatLong` function. So something like this:

```
$(".location_address a").click(function(e){
    getLatLong($(this).html());
});
```

Then in `getLatLong` function when you have coordinates of the address, you can create a marker and center map to that location:

```
if(map){
    var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLngLan, myLatLngLon);
    //add a marker on map to our new location
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: newLatLng,
       map: map,
       title: address
    });
    //center the map to the location                 
    map.setCenter(newLatLng);
}
```

Also you have to have `map` object available, so I have made it global for purpose of this example.

This is a working example based on the code you provided but I strongly suggest you to refactor the code, it looks messy and there are problems like `getLatLong` modifying `myLatLng1` and `myLatLng2` variables for some reason, not placing the marker right away, etc. You will have to address those issues yourself, I just created a working example of what you want to achieve.

Working code (click `full page` for better experience):

```js
var map = null;

getLatLong("Sarajevo");
 $(".location_address a").click(function(e){
     getLatLong($(this).html());
 })
  // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
            var myLatLng1 = {};
            var myLatLng2 = {};
          
           function init() {
                // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
                var mapOptions = {
                    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                    zoom: 15,

                    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng1, myLatLng2), // New York

                    // How you would like to style the map. 
                    // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                    styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}]
                };

                // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
                // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
                map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng1, myLatLng2),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Snazzy!'
                });
            }
            function getLatLong(address) {
            var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {              
                    var myLatLngLan = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var myLatLngLon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    myLatLng1 = myLatLngLan;
                    myLatLng2 = myLatLngLon;
                    // Add some code to work with myLatLng
                    if(map){
                      var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLngLan, myLatLngLon);
                      //add a marker
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         position: newLatLng,
                         map: map,
                         title: address
                      });
                  
                      map.setCenter(newLatLng);
                    }
          
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
            }
```

```css
.card {
 position: relative;
    clear: both;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    -o-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1);
    background-color: #222;
    height: 600px;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
 background-color: #222;
}
.location_address {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #292929;
    width: 192px;
}
.location_address ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.location_address li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.location_address li a{
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"sensor=false"});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
  
    <div class="location_address">
        <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">Zenica</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```